# Carregar imagem a partir do projeto

Tags: c#, imagem

Tenho um projeto desenvolvido a partir de um console application no Visual C#, no qual envia e-mails, sendo o texto no formato html.

hoje eu coloco uma imagem dentro desse html da seguinte maneira:

```
"<img src='" + "http://www.site.com.br/logotipo.png" + "' width='300' height='70'></img>"
```

Gostaria de mudar isso, tirando esse link, deixando a imagem no projeto, e a partir dai carregar a imagem. como poderia estar fazendo isso ?

Comment: O ideal é que a imgem fique disponível em algum endereço ou cdn online, caso contrário ela irá como anexo no e-mail, o que vai aumentar o volume de dados no envio e recebimento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode converter para uma string em base 64 e coloca-la no `src` da imagem:

Vou considerar que você tenha uma `System.Drawing.Image`.

Primeiro, converta para um byte array (`byte[]`):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converte um objeto System.Drawing.Image em um array de bytes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="foto">System.Drawing.Image</param>
    /// <returns>byte[]</returns>
    public static byte[] ConvertImageToByte(System.Drawing.Image foto, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format )
    {
        if (foto != null)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                foto.Save(stream, format);
                //stream.Flush();
                byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
                return pic;
            }
        }
        else return null;
    }
```

-Utilizando a função:

```
 System.Drawing.Image imagem = .... Origem da sua imagem;

 byte[] bImage = ConvertImageToByte(imagem,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Depois, converta o `byte[]` para `string`:

```
 string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bImage , 0, bImage.Length);
```

Depois coloque no html:

```
string html = "<img class=""plan-cover"" src=""data:image/png;base64," + base64String + """>";
```

Obs. Se você precisa definir o tamanho da imagem (menor que o original), compensa redimensionar o objeto `Image` e não no `html`. A quantidade de dados enviada será somente o necessário.